# $e\cdot(m(m-1)+1)\cdot k\cdot ( 1-\frac{1}{k})^m\leq 1$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

I have to show that $e\cdot(m(m-1)+1)\cdot  k\cdot ( 1-\frac{1}{k})^m\leq 1$ holds for all positive integers k and m whenever $m>4\cdot k\cdot log(k)$.

I replaced $(1-\frac{1}{k})^m$ with $((1-\frac{1}{k})^k))^{\frac{m}{k}}=(\frac{1}{e})^{\frac{m}{k}}$ which leads by using the condition for m to $\frac{1}{k^4}$.
But then I don't know how to work on (if this replacement actually makes sense and is not useless).
Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: the equality is wrong

Comment: How about take the log of both sides and try work out the algebra from there?